# How to link to another view of storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, button, view, storyboard

I have a login system ready on the view when the app is opened. I made it so when the login button is clicked, it says correct, but how do I link it to another view in my storyboard? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having a lot of information here I'm going to make some assumptions.  I assume that you'll want to validate the credentials before you transition to another controller.  So you'll want to validate your credentials, then call performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: with the identifier of the segue you've defined in your storyboard.

Comment: Thanks, that kind of works, but I connected a segue from the login button to the view controller. It then always links to that controller even when the credentials are wrong.

Comment: Right, in that case, don't connect the segue from the button, but from the Controller itself.  That way you can trigger it manually, and not via the button press.

Comment: Hi, that still doesn't work. I have a segue from the controller on to the controller I am linking to, and I named the segue 123. Then in my ViewController.m I have an if statement to see if the user key is 623.  If it is I called performSegueWithIdentifier:123. It does not work though. Everything compiles.

Comment: What kind of segue is it? May need to see code and storyboard screenshot.

Comment: Modal. Des this matter? What should it be?

Comment: Modal is fine.   Are you getting an error? or it it just doing nothing?  Is the performSegueWithIdentifier call actually being invoked?

Comment: No error, it just doesn't do anything. How to I tell if its being invoked?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on that line and see if its hit when you tap the button.

Comment: Nothing happens. There is only a warning next to it: "Expression result unused"

Comment: I think I'm using it incorrectly. I have written plain 'performSegueWithIdentifier:123; and that doesn't work; what am I supposed to do?

Comment: Please post your button press code

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you taking a look at http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1 as it is a well explained tutorial. It is actually a 2 part tutorial set on storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer here :

**First**, set the `Storyboard ID` of your View Controller in the Interface Builder.

**Then**, you can do, assuming you have a `navigationController` :

```
YourViewController *viewController = [[YourViewController alloc] init];
viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllerName"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

If you don't have a navigationController, you can present it instead :

```
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In presentViewController:viewController, does viewController represent the ID of the view controller? If so, it does not work for me.